# Cocoa pods installation issue

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

So I installed the AWS frameworks into my app, after already having the google maps frameworks installed with no problem at all. It seemed to of picked up a lot of errors.

At first I had two errors in total, "Could not include of non-modular header inside framework module '...'" and "Could not build objective-C module 'AWSS3'". Thus I followed a few threads to fix it and it seemed of made it worse of. Heres what I followed:

- Clean and build
- Delete DerivedData folder
- Change the framework search path
- Uninstalled and reinstalled CocoaPods
- Cleaned and built every single scheme separately.

Because I changed the search path the number of errors went up from 2 to 9, most of them being "could not include non-modular..." as well as a new one "Definition of '...' must be imported from module '...'".  For some reason I also seem to get a lot of warnings saying "Duplicate definition of category 'AWS' on interface '...'" too. In total I've picked up 25 issues, which is slightly concerning as I don't want to do anything further mess up my project completely.

CocoaPods will be the death of me.

Update: After changing some things in user paths further, I now have the problem of no module found.

Answer (score 0):

To solve problem "no module found": try enabling Modules (C and Objective-C) as below image:
[image: enable modules]

Comment: @luke Ever figure out the issue? I'm running into the same thing.